# 404 Error Web Exception

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wcf, wcf-security, system.net.webexception

the application is sending request to service but from httpGetresponse service url (https://prddb02:14448/service.svc) it returns 404 error.

What can be the reason for the errors?

When i run the https://prddb02:14448/service.svc(dev server) in web browser it runs giving certificate error but i ignore the warning and go ahead and i am able to see the wsdl file.

Where am i going wrong?Please suggest any ways to tackle this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong one:

`<endpoint address="json" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Contract.IService" behaviorConfiguration="web" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBinding"></endpoint>`

Right One
`<endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Contract.IService" behaviorConfiguration="web" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBinding"></endpoint>`

Hope it will help people who will be new to web service.